# Line break in multiple select output (Bootstrap Select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I am trying to have multiple select options in HTML to output every selection in a new line.

```
<select class"selectpicket" multiple="multiple">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to have all of the selected options inside a variable, but with a new line for each selection.

If I am inserting everything into a variable now, I would get: "Option 
 1Option 2Option 3"

I want:

Option 1

Option 2

Option 3

Thank you.

Comment: show your js code?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I don't have any JS code yet. I need help with it.